# Add ID when draggable is dropped in a droppable zone - jQuery Draggables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm using jQuery draggables on this page:

Once the user has dragged one of the draggables into the drop zone, I've added a `fadeIn` for a button to "save" the value dragged there.

I want to get the content (word) inside the draggable that is placed in the drop zone. To do this I think I need to add an ID only when that particular draggable is added into that particular droppable zone.

Then I can use `getElementById` to grab the inner value.

My issue is, adding an ID using the following:

```
$('element').attr('id', 'value');
```

But I'm unsure how to select JUST the draggable that was placed in the dropzone this time... not all of the draggables on the page.

This is the code for when something is dropped in place:

```
drop: function() {
    $(this).droppable('disable');
  },
```

Above code is currently used to disable the droppable zone (and thus stick the draggable in place, so it cannot be removed).

Answer (score 0):

The element should be passing to the function try the following:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.draggable.text());
  },
```

Check http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything. Tried attributing droppedOne as the value on the drop() function as posted in the OP but does not change.

Comment: Yeah I just want to grab the word and store it in a PHP var (could be jQuery var, just SOMEWHERE). But it needs to occur on a separate script run. See my link. Drag a green tile and button "save" appears. Click "save" and it should run a function saveWords() which stores string of the dropped tile in a variable to be used later.

Comment: I've tried with your changed code but do not ever get any feedback. No alert, nor any extra ID.

Comment: Sorry I can't see your link... it should work to get the element text http://jsfiddle.net/_wilmer/bFQ8h/1/